# How to check whether physical page is in-use?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, memory-management

I am implementing `kernel thread` which scans whole physical pages in memory and inspect physical page frame numbers of in-used pages. 
At first, I thought I can check whether specific page is used by `PG_lru flag` but the scan result came out strangely.

Is there other way to inspect page is in-use or free?

Should I have to check `_mapcount field` in struct page?

Please help me...
Thank you so much.